# How can I make a bash script that uses the ls -l command on a given argument?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

How can I make a bash script that uses the ls -l command on a given argument? I have a text document containing my shebang ect... but when I add the ls -l command, it only works on my cwd.  Say my script is scr, when I run ./scr it will not allow me to enter an argument and simply executes ls -l on my cwd. I need to be able to give the ls -l command a directory as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `ls -l "$@"` in your script, it will give any arguments given to the bash script to the `ls -l` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -l "$@"
```

Use:

```
Chris@Chris-PC:~/test$ ./scr.sh
total 4
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 Me None 21 Feb 15 22:02 scr.sh
Chris@Chris-PC:~/test$ ./scr.sh /
total 489
drwxr-xr-x+  1 Chris None      0 Feb  7 17:09 bin
drwxr-xr-x+  1 Chris None      0 Oct  1  2014 dev
drwxr-xr-x+  1 Chris None      0 Feb  7 17:09 etc
drwxrwxrwt+  1 Chris None      0 Apr 13  2015 home
drwxr-xr-x+  1 Chris None      0 Feb  7 17:09 lib
dr-xr-xr-x  10 Chris None      0 Feb 15 22:03 proc
drwxr-xr-x+  1 Chris None      0 Apr  7  2015 sbin
drwxrwxrwt+  1 Chris None      0 Feb 15 22:02 tmp
drwxr-xr-x+  1 Chris None      0 Dec 27 14:16 usr
drwxr-xr-x+  1 Chris None      0 Dec  3  2014 var
Chris@Chris-PC:~/test$
```

Comment: Thank you! I was completely blanking on how to do that command. I was confused with $*